# How to run PreTranslateMessage in MFC Dialog based App once?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I've been working on a calculator with the MFC library for a few days now. The problem is that while I have handled the buttons in the dialog box without any problems, I cannot set the keys from the keyboard correctly. This is my code:

```
BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
if(pMsg->wParam == '1') 
{ 

UpdateData(TRUE);
    AddNextCharToValue(_T("1"));//Add and show result to edit control

    UpdateData(FALSE);
} 
return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

So, the result should be: "1" but I got "111".

I assume this is because the method is called in a loop (all the time). Is there any way to make it execute once?

Have a good day

BushyAxis793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `pMsg->message` field to know what kind of message you are receiving, before you can interpret `pMsg->wParam` and `pMsg->lParam` correctly.  The code you have shown should be processing only [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown)/[`WM_KEYUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup) and/or [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) messages, eg:

```
BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
    if ((pMsg->message == WM_CHAR) && (pMsg->wParam == '1'))
    { 
        UpdateData(TRUE);
        AddNextCharToValue(_T("1"));//Add and show result to edit control
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    } 
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```